# Optimizing a Daisy Chained Asymetrical Wireless Radio Connection

Tags: wireless, tcp-ip

I asked this question in network engineering but it has failed to get any responses, so I have brought it here for the wider EE community just in case anyone can speak authoritatively on the subject.

I have a series of radio sites are connected as follows:

A-B-C-D

Sites have the following radios:

A - AP- rocket m5

B -AP, STATION 2x nanostation

C- AP, Station 2x nano station

D-Station 1 x nano station

The data to be transfered is nearly entirely in one direction- D->A, with each site producing data and sending it to A.

Couple Questions:

1. What optimizations can be made that allow assyemtrical information to transfer faster? (packet size, Timeouts, etc)
2. What optimizations can be made that will help speed up Daisy chain style connections such as this one?

Note this is not a question specific to the hardware mentioned, just to TCP/IP and radio.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is a wifi network, so here are few suggestions from an RF point of view:
1. Since node D does not communicate directly with node A, you can divide the network into 3 segments, each on a different wifi channel. Nodes C and B each have 2 APs, so it can be done easily.
2. Directional antennas on adjacent nodes, pointed at each other, will improve link budget in this case, assuming the stations are not moving.

Comment: I have already divided the network into 3 individual networks and chained them using a switch, the hardware is as well setup as I expect it can be, however Im wondering how to optimise traffic flow

What sort of optimisations can be done in the flow control of the radios?

Thank you